# Promise: .then() not getting called when returning promise from React Native Component Prop Function

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native component like below:

```
export const SearchBar = (props: SearchListProps) => {
  const {
    data,
    matchingFunction,
    listItemVariant,
    onChange,
    onSubmit,
    renderItem,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
  const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const listData = useRef([...data]);

  if (isFocused) {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue.current, {
      duration: 100,
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const promise = props?.dataSource(searchValue);
    console.log('RETURNED: ' + JSON.stringify(promise));
    promise
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, [searchValue]);

//... rest of the code
```

Then I'm using this component somewhere like this:

```
      <SearchBar
        listItemVariant={'withImage'}
        dataSource={async (query?: string) => {
          console.log('Query Passed: ' + query);
          return new Promise<ListItem[]>((resolve, _) => {
            resolve([
              {
                title: 'Paneer Bhurji',
                subTitle: 'Delicious',
                imageSource:
                  'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png',
              },
              { title: 'Paneer Butter Masala', subTitle: 'High Protein' },
              {
                title: 'Chicken',
                imageSource:
                  'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png',
              },
            ]);
          });
        }}

// ...rest of the code
```

Problem is that **.then() is not being called in the component.**
Console prints the following statements:

1. Query Passed:
2. RETURNED: {}

I'm not sure why {} is being returned when I'm returning a promise which contains some data.

**Other logs (inside useEffect's .then() ) are not getting printed.** **So essentially, .then() method is never being called.**

Comment: Did you try this way const promise = ()=> props?.dataSource(searchValue);

Comment: I tried it. console.log("RETURNED: " + JSON.stringify(promise)); now prints "RETURNED: undefined"